# java gwt null pointer?

Tags: java, gwt, null

I have the following code:

```
public class A extends Composite {
    public String url;
    public String result;
    public A(String url, String result) {
         this.url = url;
         this.result = result;
    }



 public A someObject;
 public VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
 public void init() {
    someObject = new A(url, result);
    someObject.setStyleName("style");
    this.vp.add(someObject);
}
```

But when I call 'this.vp.add(...)' it says:

```
  (TypeError): Cannot read property '__gwt_resolve' of null
```

How can that be??

Comment: The definition of `reviewHistoryTable`?

Comment: sry typo, should be 'someObject'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Composite` widget is missing a call to `initWidget()`. If it were a `Widget` it would probably be missing a call to `setElement()`.

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets

Answer (score 2):

`add` method of `VerticalPanel` takes widget as argument. But your class  A does not extend Widget.
For more information and how to use refer here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.java?r=1288

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is a bit too simplified to really tell, but you can only [add `Widget`'s](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) to GWT `Panel`'s so perhaps your `A` class is not a `Widget`? It certainly isn't in your example. Also, a widget should call `setElement(...)` to "announce" it's DOM part.

Try

```
public class A extends Widget {
    public String url;
    ...
    // etc

    public A(String url, String result) 
    { 
        setElement( whateverDOMelementYouHave ); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Cheers,